# TS2430 error in angularjs/angular 6 hybrid application

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angular, visual-studio-2017, angular-hybrid

I'm getting a compilation error in my hybrid `angularjs/angular6` application.

It occurs in `~\node_modules\@angular\upgrade\static\src\common\angular1.d.ts`file.

> Types of property '$inject' are incompatible.
>   Type 'ReadonlyArray' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
>   Property 'pop' is missing in type 'ReadonlyArray'. >~\node_modules\@angular\upgrade\static\src\common\angular1.d.ts    10  Active

The angularjs application is an extensive one created in VS2017. I'm not entirely sure what other information might be required to solve this, but I'll endeavor to provide it.

Edit:
Here is the package.json as requested:

`{
  "name": "amx",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "6.1.9",
    "@angular/common": "6.1.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "6.1.9",
    "@angular/core": "6.1.9",
    "@angular/forms": "6.1.9",
    "@angular/http": "6.1.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "6.1.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.1.9",
    "@angular/upgrade": "6.1.9",
    "@angular/router": "6.1.9",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.9.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "6.1.9",
    "@angular/language-service": "6.1.9",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "^2.9.2"
  }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Try navigating to the project end entrering:

```
rm -rf node_modules && npm install
```

Can you also share your package.json?

Comment: Thanks for answering!

Deleting the node_modules folder and reinstalling was one of the first things I did, it did not help unfortunately. Also, I've added the package.json to the original post as requested.